# --- SQL QUERY --- Which employees are older than their manager?

Tags: sql

I have a table named employee. It includes managers and employees. There is also birthdate column and i need to find "older employees than THEIR managers". How can I do it? Could you give me some clue?

Comment: Please post your table structure first, and maby a SQL you have tried and didn't succeed

Comment: you would have to use self join

Comment: You need a self-join (`employee` table with two aliases) and then compare both birthdates

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `inner join` to the same table:

```
select e.*
from employees e
  inner join employees m
    on e.managerid = m.id
   and e.birthdate < m.birthdate
```

or `exists()` in the `where`:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where exists (
  select 1
  from employees m
  where e.managerid = m.id
    and e.birthdate < m.birthdate
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your employees structure is something like:

```
id,
name,
birthdate,
manager_id
```

This could be a solution:

```
select id,  name
from employees e
where
  exists
  (select *
  from employees m
  where
    m.id = e.manager_id and
    m.birthdate > e.birthdate);
```